# stop sending header and exception on every response after adding jwt auth in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, jwt

I am sending data through response.

my expected json:

```
data: [
  {id:1,name:a},
  {id:2,name:b},
  {id:3,name:c}
]
```

I am getting:

```
exception: {}
header: {}
original: {
 data: [
   {id:1,name:a},
   {id:2,name:b},
   {id:3,name:c}
 ]
}
```

Before adding jwt it was working good but now it shows every response inside original why?

There's the method that returns the json:

```
public function searchItems(Request $request)
    {
        $items = Item::where('visible_online', 1)
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->with(['discounts', 'points', 'periods', 'itemPrices'])
            ->where('merchant_id', $this->getMerchantId())
            ->productId($request->productId)
            ->productName($request->productName)
            ->productStock($request->stockStatus)
            ->productStatus($request->status)
            ->productType($request->itemType)
            ->paginate();
        return response()->json($items, 200);
    }
```

Comment: `response()->json($items['orginal']['data'], 200);`

Comment: We can't help you unless you send us the provenance of the variable $items.

Comment: public function searchItems(Request $request)
    {
        $items = Item::where('visible_online', 1)
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->with(['discounts', 'points', 'periods', 'itemPrices'])
            ->where('merchant_id', $this->getMerchantId())
            ->productId($request->productId)
            ->productName($request->productName)
            ->productStock($request->stockStatus)
            ->productStatus($request->status)
            ->productType($request->itemType)
            ->paginate();

        return response()->json($items, 200);
    }

Comment: something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use

```
return $items;
```

Laravel can automatically make JSON response from array

Answer (score 1):

simply send this

```
return response()->json(compact('items'));
```